# Getting Browsed path for exporing jasper report in desired directory

Tags: java, jsf, jasper-reports

I am working on an JSF application, I am creating jasper report and I want to export jasper report in user's desired location.  I get output when I put hardcoded path of file. Please help me getting path at runtime for exporting report.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by getting respose.getServletStream.

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) fc.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=pdf-transaction.pdf");
```

And  then by exporting:
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

```
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.INPUT_FILE_NAME,
                    printFileName);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, response.getOutputStream());
            exporter.exportReport();
```

Thanks stackoverflow.com for being very supportive. :-)